# Clearing a footer for two floated divs

Tags: html, css

This is very confusing, I'm using the clearfix class from BootStrap to try and simply clear a footer but it's not working. My code is below:

```
<div>
    <div class="left">Left</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
    <div class="footer clearfix">Footer</div>
</div>
```

---

```
.left {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}

.right {
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
}

.footer {
      background-color: orange;
}

// Clear fix
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

I have fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/RYYFw/3/

Please could you advise why this simple clearing is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `clear: both` to your footer:

```
.footer {
    background-color: orange;
    clear: both;
}
```

Please see the [**updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RYYFw/4/).

Comment: +1 When using this there's also no need for an extra `clearfix`.

Comment: So am I right in thinking there are two types of clear? One for fixing the height of a non floated container containing floated divs and the other to push a floated div under another (like in the example).

Comment: Not really. A clearfix is a bit of a misnomer. It's for clearing floats of the *child* elements. `clear: both` is used to prevent elements from floating either side of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Add `clear:both` to .footer

```
.footer {
      background-color: orange; clear: both;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RYYFw/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

`clearfix` wouldn't work since you'd normally use it to give the parent container a height value based on the elements inside it are being floated.

What you should be using is the `clear: both;`

Therefore, you should apply it on your footer:

```
.footer {
  background-color: orange;
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleafix in question is different to what you think it is.

In this situation, the bootstrap clearfix means that a any floated element with the `clearfix` class will have a proper height (by default, if a floated element is inside a non-floated element, the non-floated element will have 0 height)

(for a much better http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ )

What you want is a way to clear the footer like such:

```
.clear { clear: both; }
```

The `clear` property means floated element are not allowed on either side of said element (it can also be assigned left and right)